# C: Segmentation fault when signal received

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, signals, signal-processing

I'm trying to write a program of a basic shell that exits at EOF and handles SIGINT without quitting. It was working within one functionless c file but upon creating functions I ran into an error where EOF and SIGNINT would cause seg faults. I'm unsure what's causing this and hoping that someone will spot something I did not. Below is the function I think causing the issue, its the first thing done after the Shell reads a command (or where I'm applying signals).

```
int check_redirect(char *line, int flag)
 {
         int n = 0;
         if (line == NULL) return (flag);
         else
         {
                 do
                 {
                         if (line[n] == '>') flag = 1;
                         n++;
                 }while (line[n] != '\n');
         }

         return (flag);
 }
```

This is where the function is called:

```
char buffer[15];
time_t now = time(NULL);

strftime(buffer, 15, "[%d/%m %H:%M]", localtime(&now) );

fprintf(stdout, "%s # ", buffer);

signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
read = getline (&line, &len, stdin);
signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

flag = check_redirect(line, flag);
```

Hopefully this is clear enough. This is at the beginning of a loop, which is looking for input to execute as a command, having printed out the prompt (date and time #). The commands work mostly but act as if they are lost occasionally, which I think may be related to this signal processing error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if `line` does not have a newline character?

Comment: @FredK The line isn't submitted, except in the case of an EOF character. If There is a \n the line is take, passed through checks to see if its a redirect or cd command, and else is deconstructed using strtok to be broken down and used in the execute system call

Comment: Where/how is `line` created?

Comment: @ryyker line is created as a NULL pointer like this `char *line = NULL;` outside of the loop, inside of main

Comment: You may have an infinite loop, as @FredK may have been alluding to.  Does _...except in the case of an EOF character_ absolutely exclude the possibility that line can be submitted without `\n`?

Comment: You could correct `check_redirect` function passing it `read` variable. This makes you able to perform a safe loop. If segfault disappear you have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seg fault can occur  from an infinite loop
You have the potential for an infinite loop here:

```
... }while (line[n] != '\n');
```

Suggest checking for more than just the `\n` character.

You could use `strstr(line, "\n");` to verify newline exists before entering loop, for example.

Comment: Might a `\0` check be suitable?

Comment: @BitFlow   Yes, that could be used.  The string will eventually come to an end.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
int check_redirect(char *line, int flag, int len)
{
   int n = 0;
   if (line != NULL)
   {
      do
      {
         if (line[n] == '>') 
         { 
            flag = 1;
         }

         n++;
      }
      while ((line[n] != '\n') && (n<len))
   }

   return (flag);
}
```

call it with:

```
flag = check_redirect(line, flag, read);
```